# Embedding Power Bi Report for Non PBI Users

Tags: c#, powerbi

I am trying to embed a power bi report into webpage using the sample provided by [this link.](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/App%20Owns%20Data)

In this sample, I have replaced all the client ids and username password of my pro account.

I have set the Native app type in App Registration. When I am trying to get Embed Token, following error is coming:
[image]

I have given following permissions to my app:
[image]
[image]

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> EmbedReport()
        {

            // Create a user password credentials.
            UserPasswordCredential UserCredentials = new UserPasswordCredential(Username, Password);
            AuthenticationContext AuthContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityUrl, false);

            // Authenticate using created credentials
            //AuthenticationResult AuthResult = await AuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, clientCred);

            AuthenticationResult AuthResult = await AuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, ClientId, UserCredentials);

            if (AuthResult == null)
            {
                return View(new EmbedConfig()
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "Authentication Failed."
                });
            }

            var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(AuthResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");

            // Create a Power BI Client object. It will be used to call Power BI APIs.
            using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
            {
                // Get a list of reports.
                var reports = client.Reports.GetReports();

                // Get the first report in the group.
                var report = reports.Value.FirstOrDefault();

                if (report == null)
                {
                    return View(new EmbedConfig()
                    {
                        ErrorMessage = "Group has no reports."
                    });
                }
                string accessLevel = "View";
                // Generate Embed Token.
                var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel, report.DatasetId,false);
                var tokenResponse = client.Reports.GenerateToken(report.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);


                if (tokenResponse == null)
                {
                    return View(new EmbedConfig()
                    {
                        ErrorMessage = "Failed to generate embed token."
                    });
                }

                // Generate Embed Configuration.
                var embedConfig = new EmbedConfig()
                {
                    EmbedToken = tokenResponse,
                    EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl,
                    Id = report.Id
                };

                return View(embedConfig);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the permission "Access the directory as the signed-in user".
I will show you how I integrate reports and dashboards for my application for users who don't have Power BI account.

1 - First I have registered the application as Native app.
2 - In the Azure Portal, in Azure Active Directory, I grant permissions for the application: 
[image]

3 - Then, set the permissions of the application like this:

[image]

[image]

And the code I use the same like you.

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: And to clarify for anyone else... You log into the portal and "Grant Permissions" as the user you want to "impersonate" from the application to Power BI. You only have to do this if you don't actually have an AAD application that is exposed via GUI (that would allow you to confirm consent more naturally)

Comment: Just another useful reference since this stuff can be hard to diagnose: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/issues/19